# Magento : Store View Theme

Tags: php, magento, themes

I have two store view (Default English and German) with two different- different theme. I am Changing my home page English to German. Home page showing German Store Theme. From German Store i am viewing a category page, this page again showing with default English store theme. While this category is attach with both Stores (German and English)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean you only want to show a German store theme for the homepage but on every other page use the default English theme? Or are you trying to show a German theme but it's not working for the category pages?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Catalog >> Manage Category

Select That Category and go to design tab.

Here check have you selected any theme.

If yes then unselect that design and save it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have set a different domains for your store? The URL has to be different, either:

> - www.yourstore.com (for english) and www.youstore.com.de (for German)
> - www.yourstore.com/en/ and www.yourstore.com/de/

By doing this, you can set in your .htaccess file or nginx config file to select the correct store. something like this:

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.yourstore\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=yourstore_en
SetEnvIf Host www\.yourstore\.com\.de MAGE_RUN_CODE=yourstore_de
```

If you want to run your website on 1 domain, you will need to use cookie to set the correct store. There are modules available. I can recommend this open source module:
https://github.com/aligent/Aligent_WebsiteSwitcher
Let me know if this helps

Comment: Hi Tran, I am working on local machine and my both theme have dropdown for this change store view (English and German) in top left.Like default Magento theme. This is not running proper on local how i make this live...

Comment: Hi Tran, I have option to change store view language from drop down.LIKE DEFAULT Magento theme (ex. 1.8). I have single site. On the base of select language i am changing theme and some category only nothing more

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with my browser cookie setting. On browser Opera this functionality not running proper but on fire fox This is running as required.

any one can suggest how i solved problem with on opera browser...

Comment: hmm, this is interesting, I will try to replicate the problem, let me know if you found something out.